# Create an android model class in Android Studio

Tags: android, class, model

I am trying to create a model class like we do in Eclipse ADT simply by creating a folder and referencing it but in Android Studio I am a bit confused.

How can create model class in Android Studio , which folder is the appropriate if I do right click on package->New->?

Comment: model means POJO class??

Comment: model class means a user that describes a user with setter getter methods , which I want to be in a folder

Comment: yeah that was also called POJO i.e Plain Old Java Object.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do like this

> right click on any package like `com.example.setu` and then
>   `New->package`.Here just give the name like `model`.Then it will create a
>   folder under that package.You can add POJO classes here by just right clicking New->Java class

Answer (score 0):

**you can create model class in simple steps**

*create a java class name*

```
public class Wallet_Model {

    String date, amount, storeid, storename, description, type;

    public Wallet_Model(String date, String amount, String storeid, String storename, String description, String type) {
        this.date = date;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.storeid = storeid;
        this.storename = storename;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Wallet_Model() {

    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }

    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public String getStoreid() {
        return storeid;
    }

    public void setStoreid(String storeid) {
        this.storeid = storeid;
    }

    public String getStorename() {
        return storename;
    }

    public void setStorename(String storename) {
        this.storename = storename;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```